# Name of connector that connects wires to washer drain pump

Tags: connector, identification

I was sent here from https://diy.stackexchange.com/ as they said connector identification is quite common here.

I'm looking to replace a connector that connects to my washers' drain pump.
I first suspected the drain pump to have gone bad, but it looks like the wire itself was burnt or sheared off. I was going to splice the wire back together but figured it would be better to replace the connector all together.

I've attached some pictures to help identify it.

The washer is an Amana NTW4516FW1

[image: photos of connector]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I know this is not the answer you're looking for, but I'd just splice the wire back together unless you have a reason to think the connector itself was part of the problem. Someone here may be able to tell you the general name of the connector, or maybe the exact style or even a part number, but you could spend a long time finding one, and possibly for more money than you think that small thing is worth.

Also, many connectors of that sort require a tool to insert the contacts into the plastic housing. You don't have one of those, so unless you get a connector with leads attached you still have a problem. And then, what connects to the other end? A different connector?

If it were me and I was forced to replace the  connector I'd check out the appliance repair shops or someone junking a used machine. I'd also try to determine what happened to the wire to assure myself that it was not going to happen again after the repair.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I don't do a whole lot of electrical work besides installing new ceiling fixtures or replacing outlets from ivory to white. What would you recommend as the  best way to splice this back together.  Since it's under a washer it's probably going to take some abuse and I don't want it pulling apart again. I was mostly looking for a new connector for that reason, I'd just assume it would be more secure and less likely to break apart at the splice while potentially getting bounced and pulled.

Comment: Strip both ends of insulation, say 3/8th in. Slip a piece of heat shrink tubing over one of the wires. Tubing should be half again as long as the stripped length and not much larger than it takes to slide onto the wire.  Make sure the tubing is far enough from the connection that it won't get hot when you solder the joint. Twist the two wires together and solder with electrical rosin core solder. Let cool. Slide the heat shrink so it completely covers the bare wire. Point a heat gun (or wife's hair dryer, or *very carefully and delicately* use a flame to shrink the tubing. Done. Continued...

Comment: ...Or, you could use a crimp on butt connector such as are frequently used in automotive wiring.. It will be quicker and easier, but a good solder joint is forever. Crimp connectors can pull loose if not carefully done. If you're uncertain about any of this, I'm sure you-tube has a million people demonstrating the techniques.

Comment: Just an update for you @mickeyf_supports_Monica, ended up doing an inline splice, my soldering abilities are pretty atrocious, but it all worked out.  I was worried it was still broke, but it was just running some weird washer diagnostics where the pump runs continuously with no water for 8-10 minutes. Thanks again!

Comment: Glad you're up and running again!